# Access b2Body from one layer to another

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, layer, box2d-iphone

Is it possible for b2Body which was created in one layer to have its properties (position, angle) to be modified in another layer?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. All you need for modification is a pointer to the body. Just pass this pointer wherever you want and modify the body state from there